# Representing a directed acyclic graph as a 2-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I represent a directed acyclic graph as a 2-dimensional array if each row contains the immediate out-neighbours of a particular node. For example, if I have an array int [] [] edges, edges[0] = {1,2,3} means there are edges from node 0 to nodes 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
List<Integer>[] adj;
AdjacencyLists(int n) {
    adj = (List<Integer>[])new List[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        adj[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>(Integer.class);
}

.....

adj[a].add(b); // a -> b edge
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: How does it not answer? just put your nodes in place of a and b respectively and you will have all neughbours for each node.

Comment: I need to use a 2-dimensional array, not a List.

Comment: It is the same...any way you can use a matrix for finding out whether 2 nodes are connected, but then you can't get in fast way, all nodes connected to a specific node.

Comment: How can I use ArrayStack? What do I need to import?

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a 2D array - given that a 2D array at least in Java can't be sparse - then you need to allocate an NxN array:  `boolean[][] edges = new boolean[n][n];`

1. You need to allow for the degenerate case where all the nodes are
   in a single chain, hence you need `n-1` rows.
2. You need to allow for a star rooted on any node, hence `n-1` columns.
3. It's vastly more complicated to store addresses in an array - given that the size has to be so large anyway - than to simple store "yes" at row `j`, position `k` for an edge from `j` -> `k`.  And it's a lot faster to update the latter.

Obviously the sensible approach would be a HashMap from source node to a HashSet of target nodes, but that's apparently not what you're looking for.

Comment: I have to test a method which takes as input a 2-dimensional array that represent the directed acyclic graph and this is why I need it. Can you please give an example because I don't really understand what you mean?